# How do I render a partial in a Text Area in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, partials

I am trying to create a email app that will use a template to create and send automated emails using an email template.

This is what I have tried to use...

```
<%= f.text_area :body, rows: "20", class: 'form-control', value: render :partial => 'emails/templates/consignment' %>
```

I just want the new email to be prepopulated with the html in my template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller use `render_to_string`:

```
@email_template = render_to_string(:partial => 'emails/templates/consignment', :layout => false,:formats=>[:html])
```

In your view:

```
<%= f.text_area :body, rows: "20", class: 'form-control', value: @email_template %>
```